# Command "ip rule show" not showing anything

Tags: networking, routing, linux-networking, router

I try to list all routing rules, and as far as I know this should be accomplished with the "ip rule show" command. In my case there is nothing returned (really nothing at all). Why? Could it have to do anything with the "ip" tool being part of the DD-WRT router firmware distribution? Any other ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that the ip binary is some special version that supports only basic commands. "ip rule show" is just not compiled into this version.